# PhpStorm hotkey doesn't work for internal php functions

Tags: php, phpstorm, hotkeys

PhpStorm hotkey for "function parameter info" is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

I get info when I use this hotkey on **my function**.

But **I don't get info** when I use it on **internal php functions** like preg_match, str_replace and others.

What is the problem ?
Thanks in advance.

P.S. PhpStorm version is 7.1.3.

Comment: *"PhpStorm version is 7.1.3."* No real comments on such old version -- maybe there were such issues in that version .. but there is no easy way of checking it (nobody will be hunting for such old version just to check how it works there). But in general: 1) check `idea.log` file for possible exceptions/hints 2) try disabling ALL 3rd party plugins (not bundled by default) 3) "File | Invalidate Caches..." and restarting IDE may also help (if it worked in the past and just stopped working now). Other than that -- try how it work in the latest version.

Comment: Just checked PhpStorm 2017.1.4 and str_replace function - all works fine.

Comment: I just noticed that "Right Click + Go To + Declaration" doesn't work with these functions. I get "Cannot find declaration to go to", while earlier I could get the declaration. This can be a reason, I think.

Comment: What I've found is "File | Invalidate Caches..." - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206760309-PHPStorm-can-t-find-declaration-to-go-to. But I don't want to lose the history.